# Jquery using multiple selectors to show all at a time

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I have jquery code to show 3 items at a time

```
$('.a').show();
$('.b').show();
$('.c').show();
```

I can also achieve the same with

```
$('.a, .b, .c').show();
```

What is main difference between both codes? Is it only the code reduction or will there be any performance related changes with 2nd code?

Comment: code clearity will come and in second statement you are searching DOM one time

Comment: agree with @EhsanSajjad, performance question better test - try jsperf to  run tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more details, when You call

```
$('.a').show();
$('.b').show();
$('.c').show();
```

It works like that:

- find all elements with class **a** and call method **show**
- find all elements with class **b** and call method **show**
- find all elements with class **c** and call method **show**

so You create **3 arrays**.

When you this:

```
$('.a, .b, .c').show();
```

It means: find all elements with classes **a**, **b**, **c** and call method **show**, so you create just **one array**.

Comment: Yes, You can compare result using Chrome DevTool (http://fiddle.jshell.net/bntq6Les/). My test results: http://i.imgur.com/dCB9wR1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

By the way you can use a common class to achieve that:

```
$('.common_class').show();
```

But with your question:

With first idea of code would perform one by one but with second idea of code will do once by searching the classes.

Comment: this is not the question